# How can I change key in array of unlimited nested children from Eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel-8

Hello everyone I jave a query that return all departments with it's children

In department model I have this relationship:

```
public function child() 
{ 
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id'); 
} 
public function children() 
{ 
    return $this->child()->with('children');
}
```

in department controller the query is :

```
$departments = Department::with(['children'])->get(); return $departments;
```

the result is:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "dep_name": "Mobiles",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "dep_name": "Samsuang",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 4,
            "dep_name": "Galaxy note10",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": 8,
                "dep_name": "Mini",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": 9,
            "dep_name": "Galaxy note11",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "dep_name": "Iphone",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "dep_name": "Cars",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "dep_name": "Labtops",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "dep_name": "pc",
    "children": []
  }
]
```

what I want is change every dep_name in result to lable and I the each department has no children I don't want to display children[],just id and label

so the result that I want to get it's as the below :

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "label": "Mobiles",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "label": "Samsuang",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 4,
            "label": "Galaxy note10",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": 8,
                "label": "Mini"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": 9,
            "label": "Galaxy note11"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "label": "Iphone"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "label": "Cars"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "label": "Labtops"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "label": "pc"
  }
]
```

I hope you guys help me becuse I stuck with this problem from long time.

## Edit :

After I saw @Mihai Matei suggestion to use array_walk_recursive I used it and it's help to achieve what I want
my code after I use array_walk_recursive :

```
static function deps($dep){
                array_walk_recursive($dep, static function($item, $key) {
                        $item['label'] = $item['dep_name'];
                            unset($item['dep_name']);
                            if(count($item['children']) != 0){
                                self::deps($item['children']);
                            }
                            else{
                                unset($item['children']);
                            }
                });
            }
```

Comment: So why is it `"id": 5, "label": "Cars"` and not `"id": 5, "label": "pc"` and the same for `id=6` and 8 and 9 and 3

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far, it may help us understand what you want

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67835982/edit) link under the question to Add More information to your question, that is where people will look for it, and noone can read code in a comment !!

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks bro. I edit it and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Should you not revise you structure in the first place?. Category > Brand > Type > Options. that way you access and query exactly what you need through polymorphic relations. Without having every thing in one table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_walk_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to achieve what you want:

```
array_walk_recursive($departments, static function($item, $key) {
    if (is_array($item)) {
        if (array_key_exists('children', $item) && empty($item['children'])) {
            unset($item['children']);
        }

        if (array_key_exists('dep_name', $item)) {
            $item['label'] = $item['dep_name'];
            unset($item['dep_name']);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks bro.
but it's only work with parents and children not affected

Comment: This answer help me achieve what I want,Thanks alot